# Runtime error when trying to use lwuit

Tags: java-me, lwuit, nokia-s40

I'm trying to use LWUIT on an app I'm making for non-touch nokia s40 devices. I am using the Nokia sdk 1.1

I downloaded the lwuit binaries for the s40 platform [here](https://projects.developer.nokia.com/LWUIT_for_Series_40).
The compressed file I downloaded is named: LWUIT-for-Series-40-binaries-1.0.zip

I included the jar file

> LWUIT-for-Series-40-binaries-1.0/bin/sdk1.1/s40-non-touch.jar

in the project build path. The project compiles, however, it doesn't run. I keep getting the following error msg

> Uncaught exception java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/lwuit/Display.

from the this line of code `Display.init(this)`.

I cannot create instances of objects of all classes in the lwuit library. Please help.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution thanx to [venky2810](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php/224945-Uncaught-exception-java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-HelloMidlet-com-sun-lwuit-events)

The solution is as follows:

1. go to the project build path (right click on project > build path > configure build path)
2. go to Order and Export tab
3. Check the jar you added, the lwuit jar